# How to get kernel source code for htc desire 526g+ & how to know the flow of drivers. How to compile & flash it back

Tags: android, linux, frameworks

How to get the Android kernel source code for `HTC desire 526g+` & to understand the flow of drivers by tracking what functions are being called. where to place `printk("%s, %s, %d",__ FILE__, ___func__,__LINE__)` or `kprintf("%s, %s, %d",__ FILE__, ___func__,__LINE__)`, to generate the logs in the sequence of functions flow. How to compile the the Android kernel source code and flash it back.

Comment: Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask about HTC Desire and Android source code.

Comment: I have generated a Back up ROM for HTC dersire 526g+ by rooting the mobile and using Nandroid backup.